# For sets $A,B$, prove $A \setminus (A \setminus B) = A \cap B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that for any sets $A$ and $B$:

$$A \setminus (A \setminus B) = A \cap B$$

Comment: This is not about terminology. Why did you tag it as such?

Comment: You do see that this is true, right? If not, try drawing a venndiagram so you get the insight in the problem, and I'm sure the answers on here will help you along the way

Answer (score 3):

Here, you might want to take the approach of using the fact that $A\setminus (A\setminus B) = A\cap B$ is equivalent to the following inclusions:

- $A\setminus (A\setminus B) \subseteq A\cap B\quad$ AND $\quad A\cap B
     \subseteq A\setminus(A\setminus B)$

You can do this by element chasing: In general, to show that one set $P$ is a subset of another set $Q$, i.e. $P\subseteq Q$, we show that for any $x \in P$, $\;x\in P \rightarrow x \in Q$.

Then use the definitions of "set-minus" and set intersection:

- $x \in P\setminus Q$ means $x \in P$ and $x \notin Q$.
- $x \in P \cap Q$ means $x \in P$ and $x\in Q$.

Answer (score 2):

Small and easy hint would be the use of this fact: $$A-B=A\cap B'$$

Answer (score 2):

My favourite approach: translate from the set level to the element level, start at the most complex side, and simplify:
\begin{align}
& x \in A \setminus (A \setminus B) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\setminus\;$"} \\
& x \in A \land \lnot (x \in A \setminus B) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\setminus\;$"} \\
& x \in A \land \lnot (x \in A \land \lnot (x \in B)) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"DeMorgan"} \\
& x \in A \land (\lnot (x \in A) \lor x \in B) \\
\end{align}
Now distribute $\;\land\;$ over $\;\lor\;$, and simplify, and you've almost completed your proof.