# Suppose $A$ and $B$ are sets. Prove that $A\setminus(A\setminus B)=A\cap B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Not a duplicate of

[For sets $A,B$, prove $A \setminus (A \setminus B) = A \cap B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569420/for-sets-a-b-prove-a-setminus-a-setminus-b-a-cap-b)

[Showing that $A\cap B = A\setminus (A\setminus B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177504/showing-that-a-cap-b-a-setminus-a-setminus-b)

[set theory proof of $A\cap B = A \setminus(A\setminus B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2006224/set-theory-proof-of-a-cap-b-a-setminusa-setminus-b)

[Using disjunction to prove that $A \setminus (A \setminus B) = A \cap B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1256981/using-disjunction-to-prove-that-a-setminus-a-setminus-b-a-cap-b)

This is exercise $3.5.3$ from the book *How to Prove it* by Velleman $($$2^{nd}$ edition$)$:

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are sets. Prove that $A\setminus(A\setminus B)=A\cap B$.

Here is my proof:

$(\rightarrow)$ Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $A\setminus(A\setminus B)$. This means that $x\in A$ and $x\notin A\setminus B$ which in turn means $x\notin A$ or $x\in B$. Now we consider two different cases.

Case $1$. Suppose $x\notin A$ and ergo a contradiction.

Case $2$. Suppose $x\in B$. Since $x\in A$, $x\in A\cap B$.

Since we reached $x\in A\cap B$ or a contradiction, then $x\in A\cap B$.

Therefore if $x\in A\setminus(A\setminus B)$ then $x\in A\cap B$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, $\forall x\Bigr(x\in A\setminus(A\setminus B)\rightarrow x\in A\cap B\Bigr)$ and so $A\setminus(A\setminus B)\subseteq A\cap B$.

$(\leftarrow)$ Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $A\cap B$. This means $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. Since $x\in B$, then $x\notin A\setminus B$. From $x\in A$ and $x\notin A\setminus B$, $x\in A\setminus (A\setminus B)$. Therefore if $x\in A\cap B$ then $x\in A\setminus(A\setminus B)$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, $\forall x\Bigr(x\in A\cap B\rightarrow x\in A\setminus(A\setminus B)\Bigr)$ and so $A\cap B\subseteq A\setminus (A\setminus B)$.

Since $A\setminus(A\setminus B)\subseteq A\cap B$ and $A\cap B\subseteq A\setminus (A\setminus B)$, it follows that $A\setminus(A\setminus B)= A\cap B$. $Q.E.D.$

Is my proof valid$?$

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Probably but it can be a lot less wordy.  This is very straightforward element chasing.

Comment: @fleablood I already knew the straightforward way but I also wanted to try this wordy way as well because I "felt" in some situations it could rescue me. As I said it was just a feeling. I am very new to proofs so I try everything I can to get better at them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine, but it's worth trying to prove both directions at once viz.$$\begin{align}x\in A\setminus(A\setminus B)&\iff x\in A\land x\notin A\setminus B\\&\iff x\in A\land x\in B\\&\iff x\in A\cap B.\end{align}$$Edit: @fleablood is right, any criterion beyond validity is aesthetic. My objective was to show how to save time with similar problems.

Comment: Is one superior to the other?

Comment: "Is one superior to the other?"  If they both show beyond a shadow of a doubt the statement is true then they are both valid.  Anything else is subjective.  I dont like seeing either a wall of text that would take 2/3 of a page to print, or  three terse lines of symbols.  But that's my aesthetics and it wouldn't be fair or valid of me to judge these correct and valid proofs on that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your proof is correct.

As you stated, you have proved that $A\setminus(A\setminus B)\subseteq A\cap B$ and $A\setminus(A\setminus B)\supseteq A\cap B$ (using correct logic), so from that we conclude that
$$A\setminus(A\setminus B)= A\cap B.$$

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct, but could be shortened by considering a sequence of 'if and only if' statements.

However, if you consider $S$ as any universal set in this context, and use $A \setminus B=A \cap B^c$, where $B^c:=S \setminus B$, then you readily get

$$ A \setminus (A \setminus B) = A \cap \big((A \cap B^c)\Big)^c = A \cap (A^c \cup B) = (A \cap A^c) \cup (A \cap B) = A \cap B. $$